Why Broadcast Receiver don't work after boot completed? Android 13
I am working on an app that has AppLockService Service and that is called after boot is completed by the MyBrodcastReciver.
when I reboot there is no receiver work
class MyBrodcastReciver:BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        if(p1?.action==Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            Log.i("UURR", "Boot Completed")
            val intent2 = Intent(p0, AppLockService::class.java)
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                p0?.startForegroundService(intent2)
            else
                p0?.startService(intent2)
        }

    }

}

I am trying to handle this case
I heard that the receiver has restrictions in android 13, is there any other solution or how I can make my Service work suberate from the app?

This question is similar to: How to fix BOOT_COMPLETED not working Android. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
